# Brackets in Doctrine query

Tags: php, doctrine

hi
i have to nest some or / and conditions
but i need brackets in my sql statement to do it in the right order
but how do you make this

is should be in this form
(... OR ...) AND ...

thnx

Answer (score 4):

According to this blog post, "[Solving the Doctrine Parenthesis Problem](http://danielfamily.com/techblog/?p=37)", you need to do a `$query->where("(ConditionA OR ConditionB) AND ConditionC");`

That may look like:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from(...)
    ->where('A = ? OR B = ?', array(valA, valB))
    ->andWhere('C = ?', valC);
```

The poster does, however, provide a more generic solution, `whereParenWrap()`, by extending `Doctrine_Query`:

```
DQ::create()
->from(...)
->where('A = ?', valA)
->orWhere('B = ?', valB)
->whereParenWrap()
->andWhere('C = ?', valC);
```

Comment: Apparently the blog poster is [also in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/178129/scott-daniel).

Answer (score 0):

Addon for the answer: [Brackets in Doctrine query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490772/brackets-in-doctrine-query/4490845#4490845)

```
/*
 * This is a simple short-hand wrapper for Doctrine_Query. It provides
 * a shorter class name and a few additional functions.
 */
class DQ extends Doctrine_Query
{
    /**
     * Returns a DQ object to get started
     *
     * @return DQ
     */
    public static function create($conn = null, $class = null) {
        return new DQ($conn, $class);
    }

    /**
     * This function will wrap the current dql where statement
     * in parenthesis. This allows more complex dql statements
     * It can be called multiple times during the creation of the dql
     * where clause.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function whereParenWrap() {
        $where = $this->_dqlParts['where'];
        if (count($where) > 0) {
            array_unshift($where, '(');
            array_push($where, ')');
            $this->_dqlParts['where'] = $where;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}

?>
```

Slightly modified.
Taken from: https://gist.github.com/888386/634c51993aaf16565690be10da7b8f13a227020a

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use Expr::orX()

```
        /** To combine all the OR conditions in one parenthesis, we will collect the conditions in one array */
        $orX = [];
        foreach ($dto->userNameSearchPhrases as $key => $userNameSearchPhrase) {
            $orX[] = $qb->expr()->like('us.username', ':userNameSearchPhrase' . $key);
            $qb->setParameter('userNameSearchPhrase' . $key, $userNameSearchPhrase);
        }
        /** To pass parameters to the Expr::orX() method from an array, use ReflectionMethod */
        $reflectionMethod = new \ReflectionMethod(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr::class, 'orX');
        $orXObject = $reflectionMethod->invokeArgs($qb->expr(), $orX);
        $qb->andWhere($orXObject);
```